# jQuery fade out elements as they scroll off page, fade back as they scroll back on

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I want elements to fade out as they scroll off the top of the page, and then fade back in as they scroll back onto the page. I wrote some code that works, but I am looking for a more elegant solution. Here is the solution I have working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmmead/JdbhV/3/

I would like to find a much shorter, more elegant piece of code, but just can't quite work it out. Maybe something with an array and the each() method? If I put a class on the divs instead of an ID, it gets a lot shorter, but then they all fade out at once. I want each box to fade out as it scrolls off the page.

HTML

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
<div id="box4"></div>
<div id="box5"></div>
<div id="box6"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4, #box5, #box6 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin:100px auto;
}
#box6 {
  margin-bottom:600px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var box1Top = $('#box1').offset().top;
var box2Top = $('#box2').offset().top;
var box3Top = $('#box3').offset().top;
var box4Top = $('#box4').offset().top;
var box5Top = $('#box5').offset().top;
var box6Top = $('#box6').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ((box1Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box1').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box1').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}

if ((box2Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box2').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box2').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}

if ((box3Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box3').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box3').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}

if ((box4Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box4').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box4').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}

if ((box5Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box5').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box5').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}
if ((box6Top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) {
    $('#box6').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
} else {
    $('#box6').stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
}
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use attribute selector `'[attr="someattr"]'` with use of `.each()` method of jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   $('[id^="box"]').each(function () { // <---loop the divs id starts with #box 
      if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 20) { //<---mark the $(this).offset().top of current object
          $(this).stop().fadeTo(100, 0); //<----fadeOut the current obj
      } else {
          $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1); //<----fadeIn the current obj
      }
   });
});
```

You can take a demo here:

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JdbhV/6/)

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was a better way to do it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[This version of your jsfiddle is considered better for several reasons](http://jsfiddle.net/thinkfast2008/JdbhV/8/):

- Well functionally decomposed (its broken into little functions): higher readability for you and other coders, and easier to maintain in the future if you need to change something.
- Flexibility: you can change the number of boxes, without even knowing the javascript!
- Efficiency: due to functional decomposition, it means that each line of code only gets called if 100% necessary

Apart from the javascript, i added classes in addition to existing id's. eg: `id="box1" class="box"`

enjoy :)

Comment: Very impressive, but not worth so much complexity for my purposes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess just set a class for all your divs. Instead of calling each one with an #id

Comment: That will make them all fade out, as soon as one hits the top of the window. Not the desired effect.

Comment: not really, if you add a 'for' loop to check which of them has desired position